# android multiplayer gam

Tags: android, nosql, couchbase

I am trying to develop multiplayer turn based android game which will be coordinated using a remote server. I want to use couchbase nosql server with java sdk. I do not understand how data will be moved from mobile to database and back. Could you please help me ? Do I need to use jetty or tomcat ? Is there any other way ? Mostly I have worked on client side only so I am not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get started with  [socket programmming in java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html) , the most primary thing you should know when developing a network app.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a REST-ful interface between the client and server instead of sockets, especially if it's a slow paced game (like Words with Friends or Draw Something)

The basic idea is that the mobile devices post data on various pages you have set up using a server:

http://mygame.com/mobile/api/submitMove?id=123&player=1&move=KnightA4

the server will then read the arguments, figure out if it's valid using a database, and respond back accordingly.

Comment: I have worked on client side only so I am not aware about server side. Could you please refer me a good tutorial ? Do I need to learn using jetty or tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn about servers and develop the server from scratch, I can relate to that BUT as a client developer it may take you a lot of time to configure, develop, test, run, host, maintain, scale the server side (and ofcourse it may cost you a great deal of money). If you are looking to release your game as quickly as possible I would propose another solution. I am from Skiller and we have SDK that should shorten the time it will take you to get your game on the market. You can use built in turn based simple API to create or join existing game, challenge players, send messages and much more...

Check our [wiki pages](http://wiki.skiller-games.com) or our [Skiller website](http://www.skiller-games.com) for more info.

Will be glad to get your input.